# How to run two embedded tomcat applications in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am developing on Eclipse and am following the guides on spring.io to develop a RESTful API and a client that consumes that RESTful API. I have developed the RESTful API and it works as expected. I am developing the client right now. Both use the embedded tomcat container in eclipse. I need both running simultaneously so that the client can do HTTP requests to the RESTful API.

The problem is that I can start the RESTful API application but whenever I try to start the client I get a `Tomcat connector is in a failed state` error.

How can I run both embedded applications simultaneously?

Here is pom.xml for the client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>UserRegistrationClient</name>
    <description>Spring MVC Client that consumes RESTful API</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For returning objects as JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are the instances set to run on different ports?

Comment: No they are not, they are trying to run on 8080. How do I change the port?

Comment: That's your problem - you can't run different server instances on the same  port. As for how to change the port, you will have to configure the base Tomcat install to support multiple instances. You can find info at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt. Scroll down to the "Advanced Configuration - Multiple Tomcat Instances" section.

Comment: Since you're using Spring Boot solving this would be as simple as modifying the run configuration in Eclipse and adding "`server.port=8080`" and "`server.port=8081`" to each apps' startup parameters.

Comment: @Kryger, this is what I was looking for. I added server.port9090 in the Server's application.properties file and it worked.